# Combine 2 actionbuttons outputs inside the same eventReactive()

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I have 2 file inputs and 2 actionbuttons.

The 1st submit button 'submit' is used to trigger the table and the 2nd 'reset' to reset every file input.

When the 1st actionbutton is empty I get a warning message.

Which table is going to be displayed depends on the if conditions inside the `log()`. The issue is that when `reset` is pressed the file inputs are getting empty but the table remains.

Ideally every table should be displayed after clicking the `submit` button and when `reset` is clicked the file inputs are getting empty the table is disappeared and the warning message is displayed again. 
What I think I need is something like an a combination of the 2 actionbuttons (`input$submit,input$reset`) inside the `log()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      fileInput('inFile', 'Choose 1st file'),
      fileInput('inFile2', 'Choose 2nd file'),
      actionButton('submit', 'Submit'),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton('reset', 'Reset')
    ),
    mainPanel(

      uiOutput("choose"),
      DTOutput( "choose2" )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    clear = FALSE
  )
  rv2 <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    clear = FALSE
  )

  ########1st
  observe({
    req(input$inFile)
    req(!rv$clear)

    rv$data <- read.csv(input$inFile$datapath,header = T)



  })

  observeEvent(input$inFile, {
    rv$clear <- FALSE
  }, priority = 1000)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$data <- NULL
    rv$clear <- TRUE
    reset('inFile')
  }, priority = 1000)


  #############2nd
  observe({
    req(input$inFile2)
    req(!rv2$clear)

    rv2$data <- read.csv(input$inFile2$datapath,header = T)



  })

  observeEvent(input$inFile2, {
    rv2$clear <- FALSE
  }, priority = 1000)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv2$data <- NULL
    rv2$clear <- TRUE
    reset('inFile2')
  }, priority = 1000)




  output$choose <- renderUI ({
    if(is.null(rv$data))
    {
      "You must upload 1st csv at least"
    }
    else
    {
      return(NULL)

    }
  })
  log<-eventReactive({input$submit }, {
    if(is.null(rv$data)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(!is.null(isolate(rv$data))){

      if(!is.null(isolate(rv2$data))){
        datatable(input$inFile2$datapath)
      }
      else if(is.null(isolate(rv2$data))){
        datatable(input$inFile$datapath)
      }
    }
  })

  output$choose2<-renderDataTable({

    log()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple actions into eventReactive() by placing them in a vector.

```
eventReactive(
  c(action1, action2),{

  }
```